# PHP: Random Result once a day,

Tags: php, mysql

PHP:
I know RAND() function will return the result in random order. But I want to get the Random Result once a day. So every day there will be different order but that order should be fixed for that day.
[SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY RAND();]

How can I achieve this, Is there any way to do it.?

Comment: maybe duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040305/how-to-get-a-random-row-for-current-day

Comment: Create an event,at the beginning of each day run your SELECT..ORDER BY RAND and store it in session to be retrieved for the day.Repeat the next day.

Comment: If you want it to stay fixed for a given day, you'll just need to store it somewhere associated with that day. Insert the date and the random result into another table, perhaps?

Comment: There might be several solution, but you can run a cront job that get the random value and save somewhere as order by value in DB or in text file. Read that value and sort your record. every day at 12:01 am you can generate the random val based on your requirement and save that. in your query just read that value.

Comment: Create your own `random` function, that takes current day and row id as a parameter and returns a pseudo random number.

Comment: use a **cache** with a ttl of 86400 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `shuffleIt` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772309/3131443) and pass it Unix time stamp of the current day.

```
shuffleIt(
  $array,
  strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateString())
);
```

This will always return same result for one day.

Answer (score -2):

hope this helps

select * from TABLE order by rand(dayofyear(CURRENT_DATE)) limit 1

Answer (score -3):

You can't solve this with a single query. Instead you should create a separate table with a random order that you re-generate once per day.